# Problem to destroy or tweet (inReplyTo) with the MGTwitterEngine- Can´t pass the right NSNumber to the methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I hope I don´t annoy you and you don´t have to answer this, but 
here is a little bit more explanation of my problem. I got all of the ids of the tweets with a NSArray. Then I set a NSNumber with:

```
NSNumber =[NSArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to get the right id of the tweet in the TableView row. Now I just wrote this:

```
 unsigned long fooo = NSNumber;
 NSLog("%@", fooo) // The right number
 [twitterEngine deleteUpdate:fooo];
```

But the finalURL has a other number. So for example fooo is: `8043688359`, the finalUrl is this:

```
finalURL = https://twitter.com/statuses/destroy/62024352.xml
```

Also I get the `HTTP error 403`

All other methods like sendUpdate, getTimeline etc. are working.
Just the deleteUpdate and the sendUpdate: inReplyTo aren´t 
working. I think it has something with a wrong number to do. 
Sorry for my bad English, bad I´m a young student from Germany 
and I´m just learning Objective-C (or programming generally) for 
three weeks.

The original methodes looking like that:

```
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status inReplyTo:(unsigned long)updateID; // statuses/update

- (NSString *)deleteUpdate:(unsigned long)updateID; // statuses/destroy
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer: The MGTwitterEngine wants a unsigned long, but the iPhone is 32bit and so the the 64bit number gets smaller and MGTwitterEngine gets the wrong number.
You have to edit the MGTwitterEngine. Just write `unsigned long long` in the methods.

Comment: I don't understand why the id must be a number type anyway. It should be treated as a string IMO.

Comment: Yep, I realized that too - I just used a NSNumberformatter to get the number from the string.

Comment: This is really odd, it seems like someone would have run into this issue before as MGTwitterEngine is widely used...

Answer (score -1):

`NSNumber` is a class not an instance.  The code could look something like the following:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
unsigned long fooo = [NSNumber longValue];
NSLog("%l", fooo); // The right number
[twitterEngine deleteUpdate:fooo];
```

The return from `-objectAtIndex:` is an object and long is a primitive value.  So you need to get the primitive long value out of the `NSNumber` object.

BTW, the odd number you are getting back is the memory address for the instance of the `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the app crashes and the console just writes: "[NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" when the program gets to the unsigned long fooo - line. Why?

Comment: Then your object in the array is not an NSNumber!  From the console output it is a string.

Answer (score -2):

Aproach it differently, as far as I can tell your code is something like:

NSNumber *aNumber = [anArray objectAtIndex:index.row];
unsigned long = aNumber;

In stead of using a unsigned long you should use a NSUinteger btw.

and doing it more directly:
NSUInteger anInteger = [[anArray objectAtIndex:index.row] longValue]; // or longLongValue];

done.
Tell me if I mis understood you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doens´t works. The App just crashes, when I use your code. Also the compiler says in the line: "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" and the console: [NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b78c50'

Comment: well what kind of object is that? in the array, if it isn't a string than no it won't work, than something like unsignedIntValue could work, but this is really basic cocoa thing, look it up in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....It's not working and app get crash while executing the code....                                                                    Over console i get the o/p: -[NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7554d90
2010-12-08 09:52:46.307 Misstwit[389:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7554d90'